# How can I export the output of a command as an environment variable in zsh?

Tags: linux, terminal, pipe, zsh

How can I pipe the output of the `which pip` command into an environment variable declaration like `export loc =` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should do it:

```sh
export loc=$(which python)
```

The output of `which python` gets assigned to the `loc` variable which is exported.

Answer (score 0):

You can take the output of one command and pipe to another using the backtick(`) or if you want, you can use `$(...)`.

Also, by convention, environment variables are capitalized. Since environment variables are case-sensitive; this convention avoids accidentally overriding environmental and internal variables.

For example, you can use `export LOC=$( which pip)`.